# Trying to access an interface inside interface from the env (SystemVerilog, OVM)

Tags: system-verilog

Inside the build function of my env class trying to connect interfaces:

```
   virtual my_if  my_vif;

   for (int i = 0; i<32; i++) begin
     _agent[i]._vif = my_vif._if[i];
   end
```

Inside my_if:

```
  interface my_if();
      if     _if[32]();
  endinterface :my_if
```

When running simulation I get this error:

```
Error-[MFNF] Member not found
my_env.sv, 229 "this.my_vif." 
Could not find member '_if' in interface 'my_if', at "my_if.sv", 1.
```

_if is also an interface with the next signals:

```
interface if(); 
 logic                   clk;
 logic                   rstn;
 logic [101:0] requests;
 logic [63:0]  dataOut;
endinterface :if
```

The thing is that everything worked fine when the interface _if was not wrapped under the my_if interface.

Comment: What is `_if` in your interface?

Comment: _if is also an interface with some signals of type logic:

interface _if(); 
    logic                   clk;
    logic                   rstn;
    logic [101:0] requests;
    logic [63:0]  dataOut;

endinterface :_if

Comment: You’re asking for trouble if you give your interface instance the same name as the interface itself.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right, it's a typo because i'm trying to write general names in the question so I'm changing the real names.. the interface is of type if and it's instance is _if. fixed it now in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to instantiate some design element of type `_if` 32 times in the interface, using array instances.

`array instances` are related to `generate` blocks. As a result the only way to index them is to do it from another `generate` blocks. You cannot use a simple for loop with indexing to do it.

Generate blocks are a part of rtl design and in general have very limited applicability to the test bench, in particular with dynamic structs as an `agent`.

You need to re-think the way you want to implement it.

Comment: Hi, deleted my previous comment - actually when writing it manually w/o a for loop everything seems to work fine.. but I though that a for loop can be used inside a class? or is there an issue because the ARRAY interface _if is inside another interface?

Comment: The issue is the SystemVerilog LRM says you cannot use a *variable* to index into an array of instances. It does not matter if that variable is coming from a procedural `for` loop. It does not matter whether that procedural code exists in a class or not.